# Customize wp-login.php Login Title

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, buddypress

Let me start off by saying that I am not very well-versed with PHP so any help is much appreciated.

Here is my issue. I have a social media site built on WordPress. It is restricted to registered users only so when someone visits the site and is not logged in, they are automatically redirected to the wp-login.php page.

However, while trying to share the link of the site to people on other social media sites like Facebook, the sites pull the Open Graph data from the wp-login.php file which shows a site title like this:

**Log In > 5th Gear --- WordPress**

I am wanting to remove the '--- WordPress' and have it so that the Open Graph data only shows as follows:

**5th Gear Car Community**

I found the string in the wp-login.php file but do not want to modify core wp files.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the login_title filter (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_title/). Change the title as needed. This can go in the functions.php file or a custom plugin.

for example:

```
add_filter('login_title', custom_login_title, 99);
function custom_login_title($origtitle) { 

    return get_bloginfo('name');

}
```

Comment: After implementing the code, it works fine, but now the ograph data is showing part of my privacy policy in the ograph description. I dont see anything in the code for the description. how can i fix this?